# Редкие юникод символы в тексте вопроса/ответа

Tags: обсуждение

Пример вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/626798/revisions

Собственно, сам вопрос: стоит ли использовать символы, подобные ≤ ∅ ∑ и так далее, тысячи таких значков? Картинки из задачников довольно частое явление. Стоит, потому что ≤ выглядит красивее, чем <=. Однако, я опасаюсь за отображение их на экране, за то, что нету в шрифтах таких значков и их заменят различного вида квадраты и вопросительные знаки. У меня (Firefox, Windows) отображается многое (не нашел неотображаемых символов) из [этого списка](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/index.htm), но это может быть не так для остальных. Также математические значки в [этом списке](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/mathematical_operators/list.htm). Или это страхи из двухтысячного года?

Comment: По-моему, скорее сайт некорректно отобразится, чем математические символы.

Comment: По-моему это страхи из двухтысячного

Comment: Такие вещи легче в виде LaTeX писать, а отображать с помощью MathJax (включён на некоторых SE сайтах), который в свою очередь можно настроить Unicode для отображения использовать (как сейчас markdown в вопросах в виде html показывается), если есть желание.